# Mach-o Linker Error

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, linker-errors, mach-o

I can't build my project because I keep getting this error. As I understood it deals with the constant tagShift I'm using in my code. I would appreciate if anyone could help me to solve this issue
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced the same issue someday and figured out the result as:

Here You have a `int tagShit` of *constant type*. So you can not make constant type variables of same name in two or more classes. Change that `tagShit` variable name in one of the class (may be as tagShift1 or anything else) and it will be good to go.

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: I tried to create a new constant with a different name for each new class. And now I've got duplicateSymbol  for tagShiftP and tagShiftV =)

Comment: The error doesn't show up only when I insert a number instead of that constant. But writing everything by hand isn't  isn't the best solution as I just wanted to have one constant to be visible in different classes.

Comment: I'll try to do it now

Comment: No you cannot create a same name constant in different classes.

Comment: I will surely do that when I'll get a 15 raiting)) It's only 12 now and I can't wote(

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have included *TrafficLightG.h* in more than one file.

#include "TrafficLightG.h"

Declare your const in that way:

*TrafficLightG.h*

```
const int tagShift;
```

*TrafficLightG.m*

```
 const int tagShift = 90;
```

PS: use NSInteger or NSUInteger instead of int.