# Duplicate symbol(s) for architecture(s) [arm7, arm64]

Tags: ios, xcode

I have imported a new version of a framework in my SDK. Anyway, I am not able to build on iPhone 6 running iOS 9.0.1 because of the following error that's driving me crazy:

```
duplicate symbol _IPDJobStatus in:
/Users/akiki/Desktop/iOS 9 Test/MPSDK/iPD.framework/iPD(IPDDevice.o)
/Users/akiki/Desktop/iOS 9 Test/MPSDK/iPD.framework/iPD(IPDAdministration.o)
ld: 5 duplicate symbols for architecture arm7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is happening for the same symbol `_IPDJobStatus` being found twice in 5 files. The same is happening on iPhone 4S running iOS 9.1 with arm64 architecture. To import the framework, I deleted the old one from the project, imported the new one and check into the *Link Binary with Library* section wether the framework reference links to the correct updated file. Before asking I have tried to perform the following actions:

1. I searched for the duplicate symbol inside the project scope with no result.
2. I'm not importing a `.m` file by accident.
3. The *Compile Sources* of the *Build Phases* project settings doesn't include any duplicate file.
4. The framework headers references in *Headers* of the *Build Phases* project settings link to the proper files.
5. I tried to clean the project, empty the Derived Data folder, quit and relaunch Xcode.
6. I added the `-ObjC` linker flag (in this case the duplicate symbols goes from five to only one).
7. I switched the *No Common Blocks* compiler setting to NO, though it has the same error with or without it.
8. I created a new empty project and imported the framework there. In this case I was able to build, so the problem must resides in my SDK.

Could someone please give me some help?

Comment: isn't it?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427024/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-armv7

Comment: search in Build Settings-> "Framework Search Paths" or "Libarary Search Paths" about iSMP framework. if any wrong link exist remove it. Or in your project dir may content two iSMP framework but one not be included!

Comment: the problem is nothing to do with headers. This problem occurs at the linker stage of build. If you filter the build transcript on the offending _IPDJobStatus symbol, it will be there at least twice. Either in your compile source build phase, or relating to the framework or static lib you are importing, that symbol - the .o file - is there twice. Check your build phases and the transcript to identify the source of the offending file.

Comment: I tried to search for that symbol throughout the whole project (both on my SDK and on my static lib), but I cannot find it. Also, in these five cases, the first file is always `IPDDevice`.

Comment: You should tell who provide the framework to modify it. There must be a global variable with the same name in each of the two files, tell him that put a `static` modifier in front of every variable to limit its scope.

Comment: as the error detailed in the question shows, that symbol is within file IPDDevice.o. So it is IPDDevice.o that occurs twice. As I say check your phases and your build transcript

Comment: In my Build Phases, I haven't the `IPDDevice.m` compile source because that file refers to a framework class (so I only have the `.h` file and I see no  `_IPDJobStatus` inside of it). From the build transcript, I see that the five duplicate symbol errors all refer to this symbol being found in the  `IPDDevice.m` and other five files all belonging to the framework.

However, if I try to make an SDK sample project and add the static library and the framework there, I am able to compile without errors.

Comment: Its pretty clear from the error that the duplicate symbol is in the *framework* not  your app. Did you build the framework yourself? did you clean all your targets?

Answer (score 2):

You can check your project directory may be there available framework. If available then delete it.

Comment: There's no duplicate framework within my project directory.

Comment: You didn't give the right answer, but nobody else did either. Anyway, I am forced to give this bounty and I chose you. Reputation system on this site sometimes works like the Mafia.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the same problem with the following code.

Add this to the Library Search Paths in Build Settings and make sure you select recursive, delete other library paths which might be absolute paths.

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)
```

May be it will help you.

Comment: Done, but it didn't help.

Comment: "No Common Blocks" compiler setting to NO: try this

Answer (score 1):

You can not make constant type variables of same name & type in two or more classes.

`_IPDJobStatus` is this constant type variable?

change it to some other name for different classes.

[Here you can see the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801568/mach-o-linker-error/30802067#30802067)

Comment: I haven't declared that symbol in my SDK. I didn't manage to find it in my project nor in the header files of the framework.

Comment: remove that framework and clean the project. now run and test. check if it works or not?

Comment: If not, then there must be a reference of that deleted file. 1) go to build phase, 2) Link binary with libraries, 3) select your framework and press minus button to remove it

Comment: if yes, then you can add this framework again and now it should be okay.

Comment: I did what you suggested. If I try to remove the framework, I got an error from a header of the static lib telling me it can't find the `iPD.h` file.

Comment: Going to Target > Build Settings > Search paths and removing the offending paths from Framework Search Paths and Library Search Paths will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It means in you project multiple copy of same View Controller instance (i,e means duplicate).

**Possible observation:**

This **IPDJobStatus** variable contains in the class **IPDDevice** or **IPDAdministration** of the framework is **duplicate**. Please check this.

**Note:** You should not have/create a class which already have in any other framework either Xcode's default or 3rd party framework.

**For example:** UIkit framework have class name "**UIApplication**" (i.e UIApplication.h, and UIApplication.m). So, if you create you class name "**UIApplication**". this error will occur. Same case for also 3rd party framework.